# Nuxt js Error Couldn't find a pages directory

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I changed nuxt js folder structure is here. I am getting Error: Couldn't find a pages directory in D:\sample. Please create one under the project root how do I access pages

.nuxt,
app,
node_modules,
server,
.eslintrc,
package,
package-lock

[Error: Couldn't find a `pages` directory in D:\sample. Please create one under
   the project root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcWT1.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a folder named `pages` in order to permit nuxt to generate the routes of your app !

More information here : [Routing](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing)

If you want to change the structure of the folder check this [Change Directory](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-srcdir/#the-srcdir-property)

**nuxt.config.js**

`module.exports = {
  srcDir: 'client/'
}`

your structure :

`-| app/
---| node_modules/
---| client/
------| pages/
------| components/
---| nuxt.config.js
---| package.json`

Comment: Thanks for your support actually I am using server and app node_models outside of the app my folder structure here 
`
-------- | .nuxt
-------- | app
----------- | nuxt_config.js
-------- | node_modules
--------- | server
--------- | pacakge.json
`

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your app folder please ?

Comment: You need to change this line in you nuxt.config.js : `module.exports = {
  srcDir: 'app/'
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
On this way you don't need fake copies to make server work properly. Create and pass args to the next constructor :

```
// Add path module
const path = require('path')

// Init the Next app with args: 
const app = next({ dir: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'yourwww'), dev })
```